# Wrong 1st Argument type:Found Class X required 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, google-signin, google-client

getting error in enableAutoManage Method when passing the context
basically i am authenticating user using Firebase but running my own api to store user's info

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    sharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManager(context);

    initialize();

    String first = getResources().getString(R.string.by_continuing_terms);
    String second = getResources().getString(R.string.terms_n_condition);
    terms_and_conditions.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + second));

    //Remove Text from Google's Sign In Button
    TextView textView = (TextView) google.getChildAt(0);
    textView.setText(BLANK);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    skipLoginHandler();
    nextClickHandler();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.authenticating));
    progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait_while_we_check_your_credentials));
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        }
    };

    google.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google button is tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(LoginActivity.this,
            new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.google_play_services_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}


   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage(LoginActivity.this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                sharedPreferenceManager.addDetailToSharedPreferences(GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN, account != null ? account.getIdToken() : BLANK);
                if(account != null) {
                    firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Account is NULL!!");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Google Login Unsuccessful!!");
            }
        }
    }

   private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleSignInAccount.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
```

*this method is called to register user*
                        registerOrLoginUsingGoogle();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.google_signin_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
**My imports for this Activity**

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.ango.DueDateActivity;
import com.ango.HealthFeedsActivityNew;
import com.ango.MotherOrFather;
import com.ango.MotherOrFatherDetails;
import com.ango.R;
import com.ango.global.AngoConfigurations;
import com.ango.global.SharedPreferenceManager;
import com.ango.helper.Constants;
import com.ango.helper.PatientDetailsHelper;
import com.ango.helper.RequestQueueSingleton;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Comment: Does it literally say "Class X"?

Comment: it says com.ango.login.LoginActivity

Comment: What is `LoginActivity`?

Comment: The main Activity where user sign in/up via google

Comment: Can you show the entire code?

Comment: yes..lemme edit question

Comment: What is direct base class of your LoginActivity?

Comment: AppCompatActivity

Comment: Please post your `import` statements from this `Activity`

Comment: The mention of `androidx` in the package is the problem. I've no idea why this expects a class from the `androidx` package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use enableAutoManage then you must make your **activity extend FragmentActivity**. The callbacks it makes are required for the automatic management of the GoogleApiClient to work. So the easiest solution is to add extends FragmentActivity to your activity. Then your cast would not fail and cause the app to crash at runtime.

Comment: since i updated to from 3.01. to 3.21.It started showing this error

Comment: build gradle  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'}